# What do dots in the breadcrumbs mean?

Tags: windows, user-interface, phpstorm

I noticed those little dots. They weren't there before, what is their meaning?

I found out that they are shown in Power Saving mode only.

[image]

Comment: Read only? Let me know what you find.

Comment: @BeNice I checked, it was not a read-only file.

Comment: Weird. PhpStorm are v helpful so just shoot the an enquiry. I am intrigued.

Comment: @BeNice it seems triggered by having power saving mode enabled

Comment: Good to know! (I guess.) PS is so richly functioned I am foreverffinding things I did not know existed.

Answer (score 4):

Originally, there should be directory icons instead of dots. I have unpacked "icons.jar" and these dots (or something very-very similar) called "bullet.png", so I guess that these should not be there.

As PhpStorm has no out-of-box option to change directory icons in Navigation bar, I may assume the following:

- There is some plugin installed that changes the UI look'n'feel. I could not find any of these with similar behaviour but you may want to try disabling custom plugins and check if the situation changes;
- Probably, the PhpStorm installation was somehow corrupted and directory icon is not available. Obviously, the re-installation should help.

Comment: I found out that the dots are shown in Power Saving mode only. Maybe it's there to signify that the directory hierarchy has not been analyzed so no icon could be assigned, or something like that. If I switch to Power Saving mode only newly opened tabs have the dots, the previously open ones, they keep the normal folder icons.